# Как употреблять правильно окончании : "ии, ий"?

Tags: орфография

Ответьте, пожалуйста! Как употреблять правильно окончании : "ии, ий".
Пример: "здании" или "зданий", "инфекции" или "инфекций", "компаний" или "компании"
Правило одно для всех родов? Если да, то какое, разъясните, в каких случаях они меняются. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Неконкретный вопрос - какой падеж имеется в виду?

Как по мне, для таких окончаний проблемным является лишь винительный падеж множественного числа: написание "уничтожили (кого?) бактерий" или "уничтожили (что?) бактерии" зависит от того, считает ли пишущий оные зловредные организмы одушевлёнными, или нет. Хоть по словарю они и неодушевлённые, но уж больно тонкая материя - человеческое восприятие...

Answer (score 0):

Всё зависит от того в каком числе употребляется слово: если во множественном, то "ий", а если в единственном, то "ии". Например: "В компании друзей."

Comment: при немного благодарен!

Answer (score 0):

Речь идёт о словах, оканчивающихся на ий, ие, ия. В предложеном падеже такие слова имеют окончание и: о здании, в санатории, о Марии. Но если слова на ья, ье, то пишется окончание е: в ущелье, о Марье.